# PHP mail() not receiving the email

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to set up a contact me page and currently I've got it working all the way to the point of the 'message sent' result showing up correctly. However the e-mail never shows up for me in my box inbox.

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $antispam = $_POST['antispam'];
    $to = 'myemailaddress@gmail.com';
    $from = 'From : ' . $email;

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($antispam == '10' || 'Ten' || 'ten') {
        $human = true;
    }

    if($_POST['submit'] &&  $name != "" && $email != "" && $message != "" && $subject != "") {
        if ($human == true) {
            if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
                $result = "Your message was sent successfully!";
            } else {
                $result = "Something went wrong! Try sending your message again";
            }
        } else {
            $result = "You answered the anti-spam answer incorrectly. Please try again.";
        }
    } else {
        $result = "You did not fill out a required field. Please try again.";
    }

?>

<?php echo $result; ?>
```

I've read seperately that Gmail has issues with PHP mail(), is that possibly the cause?

Comment: `if (antispam` right there, is an undefined constant error and that conditional's failing for another reason, being invalid. We also don't know what the form looks like.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I dont quite understand. When i enter the correct value on the first screen and submit I get `$result = "Your message was sent successfully!";` which tells me its working? But i still never recieve my email

Comment: See for yourself. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php set to catch and display and you'll see what I mean. This whole bit `if (antispam == '10' || 'Ten' || 'ten') {
        $human = true;
    }` isn't working at all here; 2 major errors in there. check your spam also.

Comment: can u try it like this <?php mail($to,$subject,$message,"From: ".$subject."<".$email.">" . "\r\n"); ?> and see if that work or not

Comment: @Fred-ii- alright I found  one issue and feel dumb for not seeing it. `if(antispam` was supposed to be `if($antispam` so I changed that but I still don't receive the email (i checked the spam folder too)

Comment: try using a basic mailing example without all the conditionals. If and when things start to work, put your conditionals back in one by one and retest. Once it starts to fail, you'll know what to go after.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I found the answer and posted it below. To be short I never told it to actually send the email, just check if it was possible then set the result variable.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer and honestly feel dumber for not recognizing it.

It was never told to send the email, just check if sending it would be true or not. I know that sounds weird but here's the old code:

```
         if ($human == true) {
            if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
                $result = "Your message was sent successfully!";
            } else {
                $result = "Something went wrong! Try sending your message again";
            }
```

and here's the fixed version

```
         if ($human == true) {
            mail($to, $subject, $body, $from);
            if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
                $result = "Your message was sent successfully!";
            } else {
                $result = "Something went wrong! Try sending your message again";
            }
```

to be short, I added `mail($to, $subject, $body, $from);` after the check to see `if $human == true`

Comment: Slow troubleshooting paid off I see ;-) Glad to hear it, *cheers*

Comment: Sending the `mail()` twice just sends the mail twice. Indicates SMTP graylisting, btw. And your "fixed" code will just get you RBL-banned somewhen.